# Searching through a MongoDB database

Tags: java, mongodb, search, recursion

Sorry for the vague post title; I couldn't figure out how to describe my situation.

I have a collection full of documents like this:

```
{ author: "Bob", category: "A" }
{ author: "Bob", category: "B" }
{ author: "Jeff", category: "B" }
{ author: "Jeff", category: "C" }
{ author: "Jim", category: "C" }
{ author: "TheOddOne", category: "D" }
```

I want to get all of the documents that are associated with an author, then get all of the documents associated with the categories of those documents. I then want to get all of the documents associated with the authors of the matched documents, and then all of the documents in those authors' categories, and so on.

I knew this would be hard to explain in words, so this is why I have a sample dataset and "query". Running this query using `Bob` should return all of the records in the above dataset except for the one in category D, because that document is not linked to the others.

Thanks in advance.

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to do this that isn't just a brute-force recursive algorithm that would have *O*(*n*<sup>*n*</sup>) queries for a certain dataset.

Comment: Is it necessary to write a query to get the specific author's records? If you're writing this in a program, wouldn't it be simpler to execute a more simple query to grab all the records and iterate through them in the program, just taking the ones with the author you want?

Based on my knowledge of databases - which is existent, if not extensive - it would be difficult to write a query to just get records for a specific author which wasn't very complex and sluggish.